# Are 辞書形 + て and 「とらんで」 from some dialect?

Tags: dialects, grammar

I'm struggling to understand this sentence from a story I'm reading:

> 「あんたが心配することはない。高校ぐらいちゃんと通わせたる。それが、親の役目ってもんやないの」
>
> おれ、高校に行ってもええのかと尋ねた息子に、母の由美子は一度、大仰に眉をひそめ、それから自分の胸をこぶしで叩き、はっきりと言い切った。
>
> 「おまえは小さいときから気を回しすぎなんよ。今日び、高校ぐらい**出とらんで**どうするの。兄ちゃんたちだって、仕送り**するて言うて**くれてるんや。うじうじ変な心配、せんときよ」

The general context is about a middle school which is being closed, and here the mother of one of the third year students is speaking with her son.

I'm guessing it's dialectal, since in that story there are a lot of things that sounds dialectal or gergal (「ええ」 instead of 「いい」, 「やな」 instead of 「だな」, 「できんようになる」 instead of 「できないようになる」), but I wasn't able to find anything about that, and I'm not sure how to look for info: I tried my grammars and googling for 「辞書形 + て」, but I didn't find anything (at least, anything in English).

I think the general meaning is something like, the mother is saying to her son to not worry so much, since he will be able to attend properly at least high school, and that's the role of parents, since if you don't at least graduate from high school you can't really do anything. But I'm having trouble understanding the parts in bold.

Is 「仕送りするて言うてくれてるんや」 equivalent to 「仕送り**して**言**って**くれてるんや」, so something like "Even your brothers says to send an allowance"? It's the only meaning I can find, but it doesn't really fit... maybe it means the brothers went away to study and are getting an allowance to be able to keep going?

Does 「今日び、高校ぐらい出とらんでどうするの」 mean something like "Nowadays, if you don't at least gratuate from high school, what can you do?"? If so, how is 「出とらんで」 formed?

Also, is 「な」 in「気を回しすぎなんよ」 for emphasis, with a general meaning of "Since you were little you read too much into things"?

Comment: I think 仕送りするて言うて is 仕送りすると言って

Comment: ^ そうですね、「～て[言]{ゆ}うて」って、関西弁なんですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

仕送りするて言うて is equivalent not to 仕送りして言って, but to 仕送りするって言って. In standard Japanese, the sentence would be 兄ちゃんたちだって仕送りするって言ってくれてるんだ, 'Your brothers are saying they'll send you an allowance, too'.

出とらんで is 出て + おる +　negative ん + て. If you understand that negative ん comes from historical ぬ, then I think you would agree that んで is a fairly natural て form. 出ておる also contracts to 出とる. In standard Japanese, it would be 今日び、高校ぐらい出てなくてどうするの. (By the way, there is another possible ～とらんで, though it doesn't apply here, which is this negative ～とらん + dialectal emphatic particle で, roughly equivalent to standard よ.)

Regarding 気を回しすぎなんよ, Kansai-ben often reduces the の of のだ constructions to ん in places where standard Japanese doesn't, so in standard Japanese the phrase would be お前は小さいときから気を回しすぎなのよ, 'Ever since you were little you've always worried too much'.

Comment: すみません、間違えました！ 「おまえは小さいときから気を回しすぎな**ん**よ。」（[まわしすぎなんよ]{HHHHHLLL} = 関東弁だと、[まわしすぎなのよ]{LHHHHHLL}）のタイポだと思います、たぶん・・・・

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that 「ん」 while transcribing, thanks.

Comment: @Aeon Akechi, thanks for the edits, I think now it's clearer; I still can't understand the first sentence, though, 「兄ちゃんだって仕送りするって言ってくれるんだ」: "I said event to your brothers I will give them an allowace", with the mother as unspoken subject? Or ar the brothers the subject? Any translation I try doesn't seem to find, so I can't understand that part.

Comment: @Mauro The subject of くれる *cannot* be the speaker. (Well, usually. I think くれてやる is always the speaker, and a demon lord in an anime might say 「チリにしてくれるわ！」, but in most actually relevant cases くれる will be someone else. I will make further edits.